# Magento 2 - empty URL Key for home page

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite, magento2.4.4, home, url-key

Our site home page URL is `https://example.com`

But the corresponding CMS Page in Magento 2.4.4 has `home` as the URL Key.

As a result, the home page can also be browsed at `https://example.com/home`

We do not want to allow it.

Things we tried:

1. Set the `URL Key` to empty

   - Result: `This identifier is reserved for "CMS Home Page" in configuration.`
2. Set the `URL Key` to `/`

   - Result: `This identifier is reserved for "CMS Home Page" in configuration.`
3. Set a URL Rewrite, from `home` to `/`

   - Result: `Request Path for Specified Store already exists.`

So what? Are we condemned to have the home page also browsable from an arbitrary URL?

Comment: im curious as to why this is an issue? your homepage is likely also browsable by the similarly arbitary https://example.com/index.php

Comment: @bjornredemption - I checked /index.php and it is not browsable; it results in 404 page. We use ScandiPWA theme, and it renders /home completely broken. We can't spend time/money fixing the broken rendering. If only we can redirect or just remove /home, our problem is resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of [**custom Fastly VCL snippets**](https://github.com/fastly/fastly-magento2/blob/master/Documentation/Guides/CUSTOM-VCL-SNIPPETS.md) is what worked for us. (The store is hosted at Adobe's Magento Cloud.)

This configuration can be found at:

- Magento admin > Stores > Configuration > Advanced > System > Full Page Cache > Fastly Configuration > [Custom VCL Snippets](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-cloud-service/user-guide/cdn/custom-vcl-snippets/fastly-vcl-custom-snippets.html?lang=en)

The ["Redirects" documentation from Fastly](https://developer.fastly.com/solutions/tutorials/redirects/) helped on creating the specific necessary VCL snippets.

**recv**

```
if (req.url.path == "/home") {
  error 618 "redirect";
}
```

**error**

```
if (obj.status == 618 && obj.response == "redirect") {
  set obj.status = 301;
  set obj.http.Location = "https://" + req.http.host + "/";
  return (deliver);
}
```

See the solution at https://fiddle.fastly.dev/fiddle/74577b5a

Here are the screenshots from Magento admin:

[image: recv snippet]

---

[image: error snippet]

---

IMHO, this is insane. At least, our problem is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Set a redirect for the "/home" URL:
set up a redirect for the "/home" URL to redirect users to the actual home page at "/". To do this, you can create a UR**L Rewrite in Magento 2.4.4**.

In the Magento Admin, go to **Marketing > SEO & Search > URL Rewrites**, and create a new rewrite.

Set the **Request Path to "/home"**, the **Target Path to "/"**, and the Redirect Type to "Permanent (301)". Save the rewrite and test to see if it redirects users from "/home" to the actual home page.

Let know if you have any query.

**Thanks**

Comment: This does not work. As described in the question, this has been attempted, and results in error `Request Path for Specified Store already exists.`

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to prevent the home page from being accessible via `https://example.com/home`, while still keeping it accessible at `https://example.com`. To achieve this, you can set up a URL redirect using the URL Rewrite Management in Magento 2.

Here's how to create a custom URL Rewrite to redirect `https://example.com/home` to `https://example.com`:

1. Log in to your Magento 2 Admin Panel.
2. Navigate to Marketing > SEO & Search > URL Rewrites.
3. Click on the "Add URL Rewrite" button.
4. Select "Custom" from the "Create URL Rewrite" dropdown menu.
5. Fill out the form with the following information:

- **Store:** Choose the appropriate store view.
- **Request Path:** home
- **Target Path:** /
- **Redirect Type:** Permanent (301)
- **Description:** (optional) Redirect home to root

6. Click on the "Save" button to create the URL rewrite rule.

Now, when someone tries to access `https://example.com/home`, they will be redirected to `https://example.com` automatically.

Please note that you might need to clear your Magento cache for the changes to take effect:

```bash
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

With this URL Rewrite in place, you can avoid having your home page accessible from the arbitrary URL, and only have it accessible from the root URL.

Comment: This does not work. As described in the question, this has been attempted, and results in error `Request Path for Specified Store already exists.`

Comment: Are you using Nginx ? If so, you may try the following rule : `rewrite ^/home$ https://$http_host permanent;`

Comment: We are using Adobe's Magento Cloud. We don't have access to NginX configuration.